# Expess node Error : Throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))

Tags: node.js, express

server/src/index.js

```
import './env';
import fs from 'fs';
import cors from 'cors';
import path from 'path';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import express from 'express';
import favicon from 'serve-favicon';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import compression from 'compression';
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/node';

import routes from './api/routes';
import json from './api/middlewares/json';
import logger, { logStream } from './utils/logger';
import * as errorHandler from './api/middlewares/errorHandler';

import initMongo from './config/mongo';
// Init MongoDB
initMongo();

// Initialize Sentry
// https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/node/express/
Sentry.init({ dsn: process.env.SENTRY_DSN });

// Initialize Express
const app = express();

const APP_PORT =
  (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' ? process.env.TEST_APP_PORT : process.env.APP_PORT) || process.env.PORT || '3000';
const APP_HOST = process.env.APP_HOST || '0.0.0.0';

const pathToSwaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-dist').absolutePath();

app.set('port', APP_PORT);
app.set('host', APP_HOST);

app.locals.title = process.env.APP_NAME;
app.locals.version = process.env.APP_VERSION;

// This request handler must be the first middleware on the app
app.use(Sentry.Handlers.requestHandler());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public')));
app.use(cors());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(compression());
app.use(morgan('tiny', { stream: logStream }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(errorHandler.bodyParser);
app.use(json);

// API Routes
app.use('/api', routes);


// Swagger UI
// Workaround for changing the default URL in swagger.json
// https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4624
const swaggerIndexContent = fs
  .readFileSync(`${pathToSwaggerUi}/index.html`)
  .toString()
  .replace('https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json', '/api/swagger.json');

app.get('/', (req, resp) => resp.sendFile(path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, './public', 'index.html'))));
app.get('/api-docs/index.html', (req, res) => res.send(swaggerIndexContent));
app.get('/api-docs', (req, res) => res.redirect('/api-docs/index.html'));
app.use('/api-docs', express.static(pathToSwaggerUi));

// This error handler must be before any other error middleware
app.use(Sentry.Handlers.errorHandler());

// Error Middlewares
app.use(errorHandler.genericErrorHandler);
app.use(errorHandler.methodNotAllowed);

app.listen(app.get('port'), app.get('host'), () => {
  logger.info(`Server started at http://${app.get('host')}:${app.get('port')}/api`);
});

// Catch unhandled rejections
process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
  logger.error('Unhandled rejection', err);

  try {
    Sentry.captureException(err);
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error('Raven error', err);
  } finally {
    process.exit(1);
  }
});

// Catch uncaught exceptions
process.on('uncaughtException', err => {
  logger.error('Uncaught exception', err);

  try {
    Sentry.captureException(err);  } catch (err) {
    logger.error('Raven error', err);
  } finally {
    process.exit(1);
  }
});

export default app;
```

server/src/api/routes/quizz.js

```
import express from 'express';
import passport from'passport';
import * as quizzController from '../controllers/quizz';

const router = express.Router();

const requireAuth = passport.authenticate('jwt', {
  session: false,
});

/**
 * GET /api/quizz
 */
router.get('/all', quizzController.fetchAll);

export default router;
```

server/src/api/routes/index.js

```
import express from 'express';
import fs from 'fs';
import { removeExtensionFromFile } from '../middlewares/utils';
import swaggerSpec from "../../utils/swagger";
import * as utils from '../middlewares/utils';

const router = express.Router();
const routesPath = `${__dirname}/`;

const isDynamicImport = routeFile =>
  routeFile !== 'index' && routeFile !== 'auth';

/*
 * Load routes statically and/or dynamically
 */

/**
 * GET /api/swagger.json
 */
router.get('/swagger.json', (req, res) => {
  res.json(swaggerSpec);
});

// Load Auth route
router.use('/', require('./auth'));

// Loop routes path and loads every file as a route except this file and Auth route
fs.readdirSync(routesPath).filter(file => {
  // Take filename and remove last part (extension)
  const routeFile = removeExtensionFromFile(file);

  // Prevents loading of this file and auth file
  return isDynamicImport(routeFile)
    ? router.use(`/${routeFile}`, require(`./${routeFile}`))
    : '';
});

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    app: req.app.locals.title,
    apiVersion: req.app.locals.version
  });
});

/*
 * Handle 404 error
 */
router.use('*', (req, res) => {
  utils.handleError(res, {
    code: 404,
    message: 'URL_NOT_FOUND',
  });
});

export default router;
```

I am trying to get a list of all the quizzes but it returns this error

"throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))"

If someone has been in the same situation please help me please

Answer (score 0):

You should check all your JavaScript files. It seems that this line is missing in any JS file:

```
module.exports = router
```